# How can we mass download apks from Google Play and/or other stores for testing?

Tags: android

We are developing an android app that is using some PackageManager queries. We would like to test it on a wide range of APKs. We were thinking if we could get these from Google Play and/or other stores through some kind of mass download (e.g., if there is an API to do something like that), that could be helpful for our testing. But we couldn't find a straightforward way to do so. Could somebody help to point us to something we could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading APKs from Google Play or other stores in bulk can be a challenging task, as there are no direct APIs or tools available for this purpose. However, there are a few workarounds you can use to get the APKs you need for testing. Here are some options:

1. Use an APK downloader tool: There are several APK downloader tools available that allow you to download APKs from the Google Play Store or other Android app stores. Some popular tools include APKPure, APKMirror, and Evozi APK Downloader. These tools allow you to enter the package name or the URL of the app you want to download, and they will generate the APK file for you to download. However, keep in mind that downloading APKs from third-party sources may come with security risks.
2. Use a crawler tool: Another option is to use a web crawler tool, such as Scrapy or BeautifulSoup, to crawl the app store website and extract the APKs. This method requires some programming skills, but it can be more efficient than manual downloading. However, keep in mind that web crawling may violate the terms of service of the app store and may result in legal consequences.
3. Contact the app developers: If you need specific versions of the APK for testing, you can try contacting the app developers directly and ask if they can provide the APKs. Some developers may be willing to provide APKs for testing purposes, but this may not always be possible.
4. Use an emulator: Finally, you can use an emulator, such as Android Studio or Genymotion, to test your app on a wide range of virtual devices. This option is especially useful for testing on different versions of Android and different screen sizes. However, keep in mind that an emulator may not accurately represent real-world conditions, and there may be some differences between the emulator and actual devices.

So, there are a few ways to download APKs from Google Play or other stores for testing. However, keep in mind the security risks and legal issues that may come with using third-party sources. If possible, it's always best to obtain the APKs directly from the app developers.

Downloading multiple APKs from the Google Play Store or any other app store can potentially have several drawbacks and legal issues related to security and privacy. Some of these concerns include:

1. Security Risks: Downloading apps from third-party websites or unofficial app stores can expose your device to security risks such as malware, viruses, and other malicious software. While Google Play Store and other official app stores generally provide some level of security screening for apps, downloading multiple APKs from these stores can increase the chances of downloading a malicious app that could compromise your device or data.
2. Legal Issues: Downloading apps from unofficial app stores or other sources can violate the app developer's copyright or licensing agreements. App developers have legal rights to their intellectual property, and downloading apps without permission can result in legal consequences such as fines or other penalties.
3. Privacy Concerns: Apps may require access to sensitive information on your device, such as your contacts, messages, or location data. By downloading multiple apps, you may be granting access to your private information to multiple unknown parties. It is important to read the app permissions carefully before downloading any app to understand what access is being granted.
4. Compatibility Issues: Apps may not work properly on certain devices due to compatibility issues or system requirements. Downloading multiple apps to test can be time-consuming and may not yield accurate results if the app is not designed for the specific device or operating system.